# How to change ethernet speed & duplex permanently in ubuntu ver. 20.04?

Tags: networking, 20.04, ethernet

I want to  set ethernet speed & duplex permanently in ubuntu 20.04.

I need 100Mbs speed & full of duplex.

Though I have tried lots of ways to set them, I am not success yet.

I can tell you some of the ways I tried.

First, I used ethtool.

```
sudo ethtool –s [device_name] speed [10/100/1000] duplex [half/full] autoneg [on/off]
```

When I entered the above command, the speed immediately changed.

However. when I rebooted the PC, the speed went back to unknown.

I found one way Ethtool_opt Variable to Permanently Set Ethtool Command Settings.

The way is to use below command.

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-[device_name]
```

Add the desired values as a line at the end of the file using the following syntax:

```
ETHTOOL_OPTS="speed [100|1000|10000] duplex [half|full] autoneg [on|off]”
```

But My PC doesn't have `/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-[device_name]`.

So I couldn't try this method.

Second, another way is to use beblow command.

```
nm-connection-editor
```

Then, on the first window, select your network interface and hit the cog
on the second window, setup the interface Speed & Duplex.

In result, Second way was also fail.

Is there any other way besides the ones I did?

Comment: Are you talking about Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS or Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS

Comment: `/etc/sysconfig` is for Red Hat-based distros, such as OpenSUSE, Red Hat, CentOS and Fedora. Any documentation mentioning that directory is not made for Debian-derivatives, such as Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you need to do this? Are you trying to force this limit or are you having problem with your connection? I'm asking it because the answer may be different for each problem.

If you're having problems with your connection, you can open the Network Manager applet (the one near clock that indicates your connection), choose your connection and open the second tab. There you can see a "link negotiation" or "autonegotiation" option (if it's not on this tab, try the others). Normally, if it's turned on, network manager solves the problems related to speed and duplex. That's why I asked if you wanna solve a problem or force speed/duplex settings.

If you need to force that settings (or if "autonegotiate" didn't solve your problem), in the same tab you can see speed and duplex options (if it's not there, unchek "autonegotiation" option). Then you can choose any settings you want (once you network card suport it).

Comment: It can communicate at only 100Mbs. The other speed are not working.

Comment: Did you find Network Manager applet? And there, did you verify if "autonegotiate" is marked? If it's selected, then unselect it and choose the speed you want. Oh, and one more thing, is your network cable a CAT 5E or superior? If you don't know, there are different cables specs and you need at least a CAT 5E to reach speeds above 100Mbs.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu network scripts should be placed in `/etc/network/if-up.d/` (the ones which run on interface activation).
Create a script `eth-speed` there and place the next code in it (use correct interface name as needed):

```
#!/bin/sh
ethtool -s <interface_name> speed 100 duplex full autoneg off
```

Then run `sudo chmod +x /etc/network/if-up.d/eth-speed` to make it executable.
Then restart your interface with the command:

```
sudo ifdown <interface_name> && sudo ifup <interface_name>
```

Check with `ethtool <interface_name>` whether all desired settings were applied.